# Quick question regarding Larmor precession and bar magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, magnetic-moment, precession

So I was just reading a bit about magnetic dipole moments, Larmor precession, angular momentum etc., but there was one little thing that was bothering me. As far as I know, any angular momentum will precess around any magnetic field, no matter how big the angular momentum and the magnetic field is. So the angular momentum can be as small as you like. So then I thought about bar magnets, which I thought had a very tiny amount of angular momentum due to their magnetic dipole moments, for as we know, the magnetic dipole moment is the gyromagnetic ratio (gr) times the angular momentum. But of course, the gr is really big for bar magnets because it's so large for electrons (and as we know, it is the electrons that make up the currents that are creating the magnetic field of the magnet). Thus, the angular momentum of bar magnets must be microscopically small. But again, as I said, any angular momentum will do, meaning that bar magnets should actually precess. **What is wrong with my thinking here?**

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking about. You're aware that Larmor precession is a quantum mechanical phenomenon? It is something that happens to nuclei/particles with angular momentum some multiple of $\hbar/2$, although in the case of NMR/MRI scans the bulk magnetization of an object shows the Larmor precession of all the atoms together. Do you want to know about the classical Larmor-precession like wobble of an entire magnet suspended in an external magnetic field? Or do you want to know how all the atoms will oscillate if you can manage to misalign them with the field? (how NMR works)

Answer (score 0):

The magnetization in a bar magnet is due to the alignment of the spin magnetic moments of the electrons, not to currents.  The precession would depend on the cross product
$\mu\times{\bf B}$.  Since $\mu$ is aligned along $\bf B$, there is no torque and no precession.

Comment: Yeah, that is what happens when the bar magnet has already aligned with the magnetic field. I wonder what happens before it has aligned. As I said, the bar magnets should actually precess around the field due to the torque, just as current loops with angular momentum do.

Comment: I thought you were asking if the bar magnet would precess due to its own magnetic moment and angular momentum.  If $\mu\times{\bf B}$ Is not zero, there will be a torque.  The magnet would precess if it had a large angular momentum, but if the angular momentum is small (as in the case of a bar magnet), it would just rotate to align with the magnetic field as a compass needle does.  A gyroscope precesses is because it has a very large angular momentum.

Comment: Right, but I wanna know why. As I explained in the question, it seems like Larmor precession should occur no matter how big the angular momentum is. I mean, I have never heard of any lower limit on the angular momentum for precession to work. Therefore, it seems like bar magnets should precess due to their tiny amount of angular momentum.

Comment: Applying torque to a 'rotating' object is a complicated subject. In the case of a magnet, the original angular momentum comes from the spin of the aligned electrons.   When a torque is applied, two things can happen.   One is precession, which concerns you. The other is that the object acquires additional angular momentum by just falling over.

Comment: You can see what happens if you spin a toy top.  As it starts to slow down, it first wobbles, which is a sign of precession. Then as it goes slower with less angular momentum, it falls over. The bar magnet is like the top with so little angular momentum that it just falls over.  Before we continue, you should read up about procession, but it will be very difficult reading.

Comment: Right, but I basically have two problems here: first, I don't really understand why the toy top stops precesing when its angular momentum gets really weak for the same reason as with the bar magnets. I mean, intuitively it makes sense, but I can't see how physics explains it for the reason stated in my question. .

Comment: The second thing is that if the bar magnet starts rotating, then its angular momentum will point 90 degrees compared to the line connecting the south and the north pole, which is also the direction of its magnetic moment. But again, the magnetic moment should point along the angular momentum, since the magnetic moment is the gyromagnetic ratio times the angular momentum.

Comment: " I don't really understand why the toy top stops precessing when its angular momentum gets really weak for the same reason as with the bar magnets."  That's why you have to study a graduate level classical mechanics textbook.  The top precesses processes on its way down, but that doesn't change much.

Comment: The bar magnet has two contributions to its angular momentum, a large contribution perpendicular to its magnetic length, and a tiny contribution parallel to its length to the electron spins.  You care only about the tiny contribution.

Comment: But doesn't the entire angular momentum (both the one perpendicular to the magnet and the tiny amount due to the angular momenta of the atoms) appear in the formula for the magnetic moment (the one which says that it's the gr times the angular momentum).

Comment: Wait, now I realize what is going on here. The answer to my last question above is no, because if a magnet rotates, then sure, there will be extra angular momentum and magnetic moment because of the extra movement of the electrons. But at the same time, there will be extra movement by the protons, and because the protons and electrons have equal but opposite charges (assuming the atoms are neutral), the extra magnetic moment due to the rotation exactly cancels out. This then solves my main question. Thanks for your time and help here :)

Answer (score 0):

If the object precesses or not, or does something inbetween, namely nutate, depends on the ratio of Larmor frequency to the rotation frequency of the object. If you start from a situation where the magnet is tilted with respect to the field and then you let go, you obtain perfect precession only, if the rotation frequency is infinite. One may think of electrons, which are point-like with zero moment of inertia, as having infinite rotation frequency for their finite angular momentum of hbar/2. For any object with a spatial extent and non-zero moment of inertia, the transition from perfect precession to "swinging" is gradual, depending on the size of angular momentum and thus rotational frequency.